# How to understand python return function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just started learning python and arrived at function definition. I have questions about the following code:

```
def abc():
    b = random.randrange(3)
    return b
```

I want to return a random number without input; however, it just showed neither error nor anything else.

Comment: It does return a random number; why do you think it does not?

Comment: If you looking for output, you need to `print` it

Comment: Thanks. I should print (b)?

Comment: either put `print(b)` in your function, or `print(abc())` in your script.

Comment: Not sure why you got close votes like that. Sure this is a beginner question, but it has all the relevant code with a clear explanation of both expected and actual behaviors. All in all, a well posed question.

Comment: @FeiWen welcome to python! Let me know if I can help you more to clearify!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42128187/6840615

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks!

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @FeiWen! Dont forget to upvote the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First work first, we make the function ,and you know how to so !

```
def abc():
  b = random.randrange(3)
  return b
```

Secondly we need to know that `return` returns  the output in the location where we called the function.

for example:

```
def example():
   return "learning"
print (example())     #"learning" is sent to this line because example() is called here!
```

I hope you are clear about `return` now! Finally for your *seeing output* - you can print the output inside the function ,which would be a bad practice!

```
def abc():
  b = random.randrange(3)
  print (b)
  return b
```

Also print the output from where it was called (like I said before)!

```
random_number = abc() # if you want to store the returned result somewhere
print(random_number)
```

or (works same)

```
print(abc())  # directly print the result; no storing the result
```

Answer (score 2):

`return` is not a function:  it is a *language operation* or *program statement*.

Since you didn't tell it to print, it does not do anything visible—computers usually do *exactly* what you tell them to do.

To see the returned value, add code to display it.  Add this after the function (below the `return` indented the same as `def`:

```
print ('random value is %d' % (abc()))
```

`abc()` is the function call
The `%` operator formats strings; the string on the left is the format control string and the arguments to the right are a list of values.  Since the list has only one argument, the parenthesis around it are not needed, but don't hurt.  An example of printing two values is:

```
print ('item %d is "%s"' % (j, s))
```

Comment: Good explanation. What's with all the parentheses at the end there?

Comment: It's like setting up instructions you haven't needed to use yet . You have to call the function now with 'abc()'

Comment: Also, "language operation" should probably be "statement" or "built-in statement"

Comment: @MadPhysicist:  I was being extra general.  I have amended my answer with a fuller explanation for a novice.

Answer (score 0):

When the function `abc()`returns something let's say int value 6. you can understand as whenever you call this function `abc()`, it gives value 6. Your code is only a function definition, and if you want to see the value, you must **call the function first** **and print to the console** by either

```
print(abc())
```

Or store the return value to a variable then print

```
var = abc()
print(var)
```

Comment: write in English please, this is not txt msging